# How do I set up gRPC bi-directional streaming correctly?

Tags: c#, grpc

There is a service called gRPC:

```
...
rpc DisplayStream (stream DisplayStreamRequest) returns (stream DisplayStreamReply);
...
message DisplayStreamRequest {
    int32 mouse_x = 1;
    int32 mouse_y = 2;
}

message DisplayStreamReply {
    bytes screenshot_bytes = 1;
}
...
```

Its implementation on the server:

```
public async override Task DisplayStream(IAsyncStreamReader<DisplayStreamRequest> requestStream, IServerStreamWriter<DisplayStreamReply> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var request = requestStream.Current;

        User32.SetCursorPos(request.MouseX, request.MouseY);

        await responseStream.WriteAsync(new DisplayStreamReply
        {
            ScreenshotBytes = ByteString.CopyFrom(Helpers.GetScreenshotBytes()),
        });
    }
}
```

Calling a function on the client (one of the latest implementation attempts):

```
private async void StartStreaming()
{
    using var call = client.DisplayStream();

    var requestWriterTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(displayStreamRequest);
        }
    });

    var responseReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            var displayData = call.ResponseStream.Current;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => StreamingImage.Source = displayData.ScreenshotBytes.ToImage());
        }
    });

    await requestWriterTask;
    await responseReaderTask;
}
```

The coordinates of the cursor in the `DisplayStreamRequest` write as follows:

```
private void StreamingImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Image screenshotImage)
    {
        var currentMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(screenshotImage);

        displayStreamRequest.MouseX = (int)currentMousePosition.X;
        displayStreamRequest.MouseY = (int)currentMousePosition.Y;
    }
}
```

The essence of the question: "Streaming cursor to the server when it moves on the client" does not work.

P.S. In this implementation, the display streaming to the client doesn't work itself, but the problem is solved simply by commenting out lines related to the transfer of cursor coordinates (which doesn't suit me, because this is the essence of the question...)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: In the serverside snippet, you're reading the request with ` var request = requestStream.Current;` without ever calling requestStream.MoveNext(). Which means that requestStream.Current will likely throw? you need to do sth like while(request.MoveNext()) { var request = requestStream.Current() ).

Comment: Also, be careful with async-await while being on the UI thread. See e.g. .ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks.